# WMI lib to start windows service remotely

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-services, wmi

How do I start a service using the WMI library?
The code below throws the exception:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'StopService'`

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ('servername',user='username',password='password')
c.Win32_Service.StartService('WIn32_service')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation regarding the library on github: https://github.com/tjguk/wmi/blob/master/docs/cookbook.rst

I believe the above code is throwing an error because you are not specifying **which** service to start.

Assuming you don't know what services are available to you:

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()  # Pass connection credentials if needed

# Below will output all possible service names
for service in c.Win32_Service():
    print(service.Name)
```

Once you know the name of the service you want to run:

```
# If you know the name of the service you can simply start it with:
c.Win32_Service(Name='<service_name>')[0].StartService()

# Same as above, a little differently...
for service in c.Win32_Service():
    # Some condition to find the wanted service
    if service.Name == 'service_you_want':
        service.StartService()
```

Hopefully with the documentation, and my code snippets, you'll be able to find your solution.

Comment: Thanks ! - I get an attributeError 

import wmi

c = wmi.WMI ('servername',user='user',password='password')
c.Win32_Service(Name='service_name').StartService()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 1, line 4
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'StartService'

Comment: Are you passing 'service_name' as an actual service name? In my code I just used that as an example... through the library you are leveraging Microsoft's Windows Query Language, i.e. you are querying for information, and with `c.Win32_Service(Name='service_name')` you are looking for a service with the name 'service_name' - which I highly doubt is what you intended. It sounds like you aren't sure what the exact name of the service you want to run is - refer to my first bit of code `for service in c.Win32_Service()`, run this code, look at the output, and find the name you want.

Comment: i have an actual server name, username, password and service name. I have just edited the 'service_name' for the post

Comment: I edited my answer to be a bit more clear - however I know the problem now, try this: `c.Win32_Service(Name='<service_name>')[0].StartService()`. Before calling `.StartService()` you need to grab the wmi object returned from the query; the query returns a list, containing the wmi object(s), so `[0]` becomes necessary.

Comment: No problem - please mark the question as answered :)