# AttributeError: winmgmts:.Win32_Services

Tags: python, winapi, win32com

I am trying to write a script to run the services remotely, using the following code; for which I am receiving:

`Error:: AttributeError: winmgmts.Win32_Services`

I tried checking this blog [WMI lib to start windows service remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036502/wmi-lib-to-start-windows-service-remotely), but I did not receive much help.

```
def start_services():

c = wmi.WMI()
for services in c.Win32_Services(Name="Adobe Flash Player Update Service"):
    result = services.startservice()
    if result == 0:
        print("Service :",services.name)
    else:
        print("Service Already is Start State")

start_services()
```

Mentioned Service should Start

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `c.Win32_Services` to `c.Win32_Service`.

There are also IndentationErrors.
And the method `startservice()` should be `StartService()`.
`Adobe Flash Player Update Service` is its Display name, you should pass its Service name, should be `AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc`.

The code that works is:

```
import wmi
def start_services():
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for services in c.Win32_Service(Name="AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc"):
        result = services.StartService()
        if result == 0:
            print("Service :",services.name)
        else:
            print("Service Already is Start State")
start_services()
```

Comment: #Drake Thanks for the response, indentation was correct the error was because I was giving the wrong service name

Comment: @SahilManoharan The wrong service name will only fail to find the service，but will not get AttributeError. Can method `Win32_Services()` and `startservice()` works?

Comment: Yes, it's working,  Correct me if I am wrong Since the service name has been passed as an attribute and as the service doesn't exist henceforth it should pop up attribute error itself. Not much efficient on it, do correct me if I am wrong